# Plone 3.0 users and groups: show all

Tags: plone, zope, plone-3.x

I have a problem that when I enter **users and groups** page and I press **show all**, 
it will show nothing or just a few members within one page instead of showing 20 members in a page like before, why is that?

Recently I have set plone captcha to prevent robot registration, is this setting has anything to do with my problem?

Comment: You see the batching/pagination? Maybe you see also other pages with less than 20 members, or totally empty?

Comment: I went through every page and I found that some pages only show several members and some show absolutely nothing...why is that exactly?

Answer (score 0):

Is an old problem of Plone 3 user and group handling. If you look at the site log when accessing the view you'll probably see something like "*Skipped user without principal object ...*".

It mean that the `portal_memberdata` tool contains some old user data that are not referring to real users: probably you changed something in the user and groups management, like removing a source of users.

Unluckily Plone 3 do not offer a way to fix this in a simple way. On Plone 4 the `portal_memberdata` from ZMI offer a way to cleanup things.

This is not blocking your site from working normally and is not a critical problem (although I understand is annoying)

Comment: Thank you for answering. 


I went to portal_memberdata and click view, I saw nothing but the home page of my website...it did not show any other messages...why? 


Can you please tell me how to fix this? Since I have to go through all member pages to see if there are new members everyday, this is really annoying.

Comment: No I meant when you go to the Plone ui for handling users and groups and you perform a search. At this point try to look at the server instance log.

Comment: I'm sorry but could you tell me that where can I see server instance log ?

Comment: It depends on you Plone installazione. Commonly is a file called `instance.log` (or very similar name) inside the `var/log` directory of your installation.

Comment: Thanks. Is there any solution to this situation ? Please do tell me !!